# Как задать, перехватить и обработать заголовки ответа сервера?

Tags: php, apache, http, header

Возникла задача перехватить/отследить перезагрузку на собственном домене с отключенными куками. Предположительно, единственный способ - это после перезагрузки получить ожидаемые заголовки от сервера и тем самым зафиксировать сам факт перезагрузки.

Формирую заголовок:

```
header('Cache-Control: max-age=1234567'); 
header('Location: http://mydomain.com');
exit;
```

Пытаюсь получить массив с присутствующим ключом `Cache-Control` и ожидаемым значением `1234567`.

При использовании функции `getallheaders()` либо вообще элемента массива с этим ключом нет, либо (после дополнительной перезагрузки) другое значение элемента: `[Cache-Control] => max-age=0`

При использовании `apache_request_headers()` я получаю только один элемент массива: `[X-Powered-By] => PHP/5.3.5` (на localhost) и вообще пустой массив при перезагрузке на реальном сервере.

Прошу совета и помощи: как задать, получить и обработать *произвольные заголовки сервера*?

Основной вопрос: существует ли иной способ идентификации повторного захода на сайт после перезагрузки, кроме обработки произвольно заданных заголовков при отключенных cookies?

Comment: Не совсем понял. Вам надо именно событие отследить или просто повторный заход получить?

Comment: Мне нужно зафиксировать именно повторный заход _сразу после перезагрузки_. Способ реализации не важен. Если это повторный заход с отключенными куками, клиент не будет перенаправляться на авторизацию.

Comment: может стоит попробовать sessionStorage на js? И отправлять Аяксом если что то есть?

Comment: Или решение только на php нужно?

Comment: идея хорошая, но нужен способ фиксации перезагрузки с отключенными и куками и скриптами. Иначе уход клиента в бесконечный цикл перенаправлений. Т.е. только php.

Answer (score 0):

Задача распадается на 2 подзадачи
1) узнать клиента без кук
2) узнать что он перезагрузил страницу.

Первую задачу можно решить сохраняя ip и user_agent клиентов и время запроса.
Вторую - просто смотреть при каждом запросе - а не заходил ли такой клиент совсем недавно?